# Slow performance with ST_CONTAINS

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have simple sql query with JOIN which connected if point in multipolygon:

```
SELECT `oktmo_geometry`.`oktmo` FROM `place`
INNER JOIN `oktmo_geometry` ON ST_CONTAINS(`oktmo_geometry`.`geometry`, Point(`place`.lng, `place`.lat))
```

But that query very slow. I have 12k places and 300 geometry. For only 50 places it take 3-5 sec (depending on the version MySQL). I had tried use MariaDB, and that was ~50 times faster than MySQL, but still slow i think.

Maybe something wrong with my query or anything else?

`oktmo_geometry`.`geometry` is multipolygon type.

Comment: Are you using `SPATIAL` index?  With which `ENGINE`, MyISAM? or InnoDB?

Comment: If anyone wonder, SPATIAL index solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A good portion of your speed is lost here:
`` Point(`place`.lng, `place`.lat) ``

This can't be indexed, so in principle it has to go through every `` `place` `` row to complete the search.

A better solution would be to create a new column like `` `place`.pointvalue `` that is a point data type derived from Point(`` `place`.lng ``, `` `place`.lat ``), and then index `` `place`.pointvalue ``.

Then your query would look like

```sql
SELECT `mo_geometry`.`oktmo` FROM `place`
INNER JOIN `oktmo_geometry` ON ST_CONTAINS(`oktmo_geometry`.`geometry`, `place`.pointvalue)
```

I suspect that will go a lot faster.

Comment: The problem remains if we want a point inside a region. Place can include multiple unlisted points.